KDE blank desktop after sleep mode wayland kubuntu 24.10
When my system comes back from sleep, apps are still running. I can start new ones with alt+F2.
I can switch apps with alt+Tab, yet there is no panel, no controls, no background image, no "Desktop" - just black void.

Operating System: Kubuntu 24.10
KDE Plasma Version: 6.1.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.6.0
Qt Version: 6.6.2
Kernel Version: 6.11.0-9-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel Graphics
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 14 × Intel® Core™ Ultra 5 125U Memory: 30,9 GiB of RAM
LENOVO ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 12


thx for the markdown make-up @mpboden

Perhaps it is the same thing, but according to my observations it happens when the monitor is turned off via the system: https://discuss.kde.org/t/panel-disappears-when-the-monitor-wakes-up-from-sleep-off-state/25298/2

I have exactly the same problem on Arch with kernel 6.6.62-1-lts, KDE Plasma version 6.2.3, KDE Frameworks version 6.8.0, QT version 6.8.0, with wayland on LENOVO ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 11 12 × 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1365U.
I wasn't able to found the cause of this, but restarting Plasma with kquitapp6 plasmashell || killall plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell helps without having to restart other applications.

Ctrl + Alt + T
plasmashell --replace &
disown

thats one possibility - you can also press CTRL-ALT-DEL and logout then login again -(killing most applications though) - still looking for a way to make the problem go away
